# Find how far runners travel on a circular track (trig)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry, circles

[image]

-How far has each runner traveled after 8 seconds?
Though I just had to convert the rad/sec to rev/sec to get yards then multiply that by 8 seconds, but that isnt correct.

- Find the angle θ, in radians, swept out by for each after t seconds.
  Dont know how to do this part at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula we need to use is $v=\omega r$ where

- $v$ is the linear speed of the runner
- $\omega$ is the angular speed
- $r$ is the radius of the circular track

We also need to make use of the following variables

- $s$ is the distance
- $t$ is the time which is given as $8$ seconds

Michael: $$v=(0.024)(110)=2.64 \text{ yd/s}$$
$$s=vt=(2.64)(8)=21.12 \text{ yd}$$
Tiffany: $$v=(0.03)(110)=3.30 \text{ yd/s}$$
$$s=vt=(3.30)(8)=26.40 \text{ yd}$$

Comment: so if I want to find the 2nd time Tiffany passes Michael how would i do that. I found the first time by setting both of their x values to each other: 110cos(0.024t)=110cos(0.03t+pi) to get t= 523.6. How do I do the second time?

Answer (score 1):

Michael is running at $0.024$ rad/sec. The angle he covers is measured in radians, and the speed given is given in radians per second. Multiplying his angular speed with the time will give you the angular distance covered. $0.024 \frac{rad}{sec} * t sec = 0.024 t \frac{sec}{sec}=0.024t$ which means that for Michael his angular distance covered is $0.024t$ radians.

Comment: how would I find the distance in 8 seconds in yards

Comment: @Sondra Well you know t, which is 8, so you can find out the angular distance right? If you take the angular distance (in rad) and multiply it by the radius, it will always give you the arc length of an arc on a circle of that radius of that angle size, so it would be $0.024 rad/sec * 8 sec * 110 yards$ as the distance he traveled

Comment: so if I want to find the 2nd time Tiffany passes Michael how would i do that. I found the first time by setting both of their x values to each other: 110cos(0.024t)=110cos(0.03t+pi) to get t= 523.6. How do I do the second time?

Comment: Well if it takes 523.6 seconds for Michael to run 0.5 laps more than Tiffany, then how much time does it take for him to run 1.5 more? Yes you could find the formula all over again, but since their speeds remain constant, you can just multiply it by 3 to get the time for the second pass.

Comment: How did you figure out the 3? It's correct. I just want to understand.

Comment: The first pass hapens after Michael runs 0.5 laps more than Tiffany. The second pass happens when he has run 1.5 laps more. 1.5 is 3 times 0.5

Answer (score 0):

Running $x$ rad is equivalent to running $xr$ yards. Using this you can get the speed of both runners.